# Is there a way to pass a function an unitialized actual parameter, and initialize it as an array in the function body?

Tags: awk

I am coding a generic LIFO (Last In First Out) in `awk` where a LIFO is an indexed array with index 1 corresponding to the first-in position and index `length(LIFO)` corresponding to the last-in position:

```
# push value `val` in LIFO `lifo`
function push(lifo, val) {
  lifo[length(lifo)+1]=val
}

# pop and return last input value from LIFO `lifo`
function pop(lifo,    val) {
  val=lifo[length(lifo)]
  delete lifo[length(lifo)]
  return val
}
```

My issue is with `push` that I cannot use to initialize a not yet declared LIFO. If I call:

```
push(foo, 42)
```

and `foo` has not been initialized, it is passed by value as a scalar and GNU Awk 5.3.0 raises an error:

```
awk: bug.awk:3: fatal: attempt to use scalar parameter `lifo' as an array
```

Of course, I could test before calling `push`:

```
if(isarray(foo)) {
  push(foo, 42)
} else {
  foo[1]=42
}
```

And I could add a safety test to the function:

```
function push(lifo, val) {
  if(isarray(lifo)) {
    lifo[length(lifo)+1]=val
  } else {
    debug("ERROR: push in unitialized LIFO")
    exit(1)
  }
}
```

It is not very convenient. I'd prefer a function that handles all cases. Is there a way to code (or call) the `push` function such that it supports uninitialized actual parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not that `foo` is passed as a scalar, it's passed as an uninitialized variable so when the function is called no determination of scalar vs array or anything else has been made. The problem happens inside the function where `length()` sets the type of an uninitialized variable like `lifo` to be a scalar string (to provide POSIX-compatible functionality* by default) so you need to tell awk that `lifo` is an array before calling `length()` by doing some operation on it that only applies to arrays, e.g. use `in`:

```
function push(lifo, val,        i) {
  for (i in lifo) break;
  lifo[length(lifo)+1]=val
}
```

* Note that `length(array)` is non-POSIX behavior. Per POSIX `length()` works on strings, not arrays, hence any awk that supports `length(array)` treats `length()s` argument as a scalar string by default and once awk has decided that a variable is a scalar or array it remains that.

You could alternatively do:

```
function push(lifo, val,       i, lgth) {
  for (i in lifo) ++lgth;
  lifo[lgth+1]=val
}
```

or:

```
function push(lifo, val,       lgth) {
  for (lgth=1; lgth in lifo; lgth++);
  lifo[lgth]=val
}
```

either of which is portable to all awks or, more efficiently and also portable to all awks (and so it's what I'd do, FWIW), just store the size of the stack in an unused array location such as `lifo[0]`:

```
# push value `val` in LIFO `lifo`
function push(lifo, val) {
  lifo[++lifo[0]]=val
}

# pop and return last input value from LIFO `lifo`
function pop(lifo,    val) {
  val=lifo[lifo[0]]
  delete lifo[lifo[0]--]
  return val
}
```

By the way, use of `isarray(lifo)` would also make your script non-portable as POSIX has no `isarray()` function, that's a gawk extension.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ed, your `lifo[0]` suggestion is very nice, I will use that. Thanks also for letting me understand where exactly the `lifo` parameter was becoming a scalar. I should have tested this with `typeof`, but I was so sure that it was when passing the parameter to the function...

Comment: You're welcome. Yeah, this one isn't exactly obvious - very dark-corner-ish :-).